# In Ember, why does action bubble to route from controller and not first to the parent controllers?

Tags: ember.js

In Ember, why does action bubble to route from controller? Should not it first bubble to the parent controller hierarchy and then to route?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a logically correct decision. Ember uses [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) model as basis, where "C" represented by `Ember.Route & Ember.Controller`, therefore SomeController is closer to SomeRoute (it's a single entity in MVC) than SomeOtherParentController.